# Updating time by using static variable Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, static-members

I am using a menu option to set the time for a game. By default the time is set to 10 seconds. The user can set the time by clicking on the menu and then selecting a choice. I am using a custom view, so the method for changing the time is in a different class than the view.

When the user clicks on the menu option a dialog appears with a EditText as its view. The user enter a number between 5 and 60. I have to wait an entire game cycle for the time to change, so it **should** change on the next game..

but it does not..

It will only change if I try and change the time again.

Ex)

I change the time to 5 seconds the first time I play, expecting it to change to 5 seconds the next game cycle. In the next game cycle it does not change to 5. It will stay at the previous time. I change the time again to 30 seconds. Next game cycle, the timer now appears to have 5 seconds. If I change the time again to 40, it will appear 30.

This is where I am changing the time, on each newgame();

```
static int timeRemaining = 10;
public void newGame() {
    timeLeft = timeRemaining; // start the countdown
    // do other stuff
```

This is where I ask the user for input, and change the variable timeRemaining. Keep in mind they are in different classes.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {       
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);

            dialog.setTitle("Enter the time limit");
            dialog.setView(input);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getInput = input.getText().toString();
                    try{
                    result = Integer.parseInt(getInput);

                    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                        CannonView.timeRemaining = 10;
                        Toast.makeText((Context) getApplicationContext(), "Enter an integer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(result < 5){
                        Toast.makeText((Context) getApplicationContext(), "Invalid input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (result > 60) {
                        Toast.makeText((Context) getApplicationContext(), "Invalid input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    Toast.makeText((Context) getApplicationContext(), "Time set changed next game", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog box = dialog.create();
            box.show();
            if(result < 5 || result > 60){      
                CannonView.timeRemaining = 10;
                return true;
            }else{
                CannonView.timeRemaining = result;
                return true;
            }       
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I change the timeRemaining here, but it does not update until I change it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to start the new game with the time you set in the last game,is that sound right?

Comment: Does box.show return before the user clicks Done?

Comment: It seems like the issue is related to the creation of the newGame object. How or where are you calling newGame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is you do not put the follwing in the onClickListener

```
if(result < 5 || result > 60)      
    CannonView.timeRemaining = 10;
else  CannonView.timeRemaining = result;
```

It should be like this

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // your original code
        if(result < 5 || result > 60)      
            CannonView.timeRemaining = 10;
        else  CannonView.timeRemaining = result;
});
```